# Invite Facebook friends to app on Windows Phone

Tags: facebook, windows-phone-8.1, facebook-c#-sdk

is it possible to send an invitation (appRequest?) to a Facebook friend using Facebook C# SDK on Windows Phone 8/8.1? Best way for me would be using similar dialog as described here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/games/requests/v2.2?locale=en_GB

I understand that the link does not describe Facebook C# SDK, but I am asking for a best way to imitate this functionality. I presume Facebook C# SDK uses Facebook app GUI for Login and maybe some more functions, so is there a way to use it even for sending an invitation?

Thanks for any help

Comment: You can only use that if you are a game and have a canvas implementation. If you don't you need to use the methods described at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/faq#invite_to_app

Comment: Ok, my app is a game and has a canvas implementation, I even can get invite tokens using GraphAPI://<usr>/invitable_friends, but my question was about displaying the dialog (Requests Dialog or alternative) on Windows Phone, the linked document talks only about iOS and Android. (Note: I understand that official Facebook SDK is not available for WP, that's why I am asking about alternative using Facebook C# SDK [link](http://facebooksdk.net) )